# Will hedgehogs break and eat hen's eggs?

Tags: eating, hedgehog

I've seen a hedgehog milling about during the day. It is November, the temperature has recently gone below freezing at night, and the hedgehog looked pretty small, say the size of a large potato. These factors all add up to [pretty bad news](http://www.hedgehog-rescue.org.uk/leavealone.php) for a hedgehog, so I've decided to try and capture this little one and take it to a rescue centre, as it is pretty likely it won't survive on its own.

To encourage it to come back, I bought some cat food, which I left in a sheltered place near where I saw the 'hog, and in under an hour the food has disappeared. However there are at least half a dozen cats living in close proximity to my property so it's more than likely one of them has had it.

So I've had an idea: Give the hedgehog something that is nutritious for it, but that cats can't or won't eat. [Some sources](https://www.hedgehogstreet.org/about-hedgehogs/diet/) suggest that they will eat eggs, so I was wondering - will a hedgehog recognise a hen's egg as food and be able to break into it? I would imagine it extremely unlikely that a cat would eat raw egg if it came across it, and even if it would, is unlikely to know how to break an egg without being taught. So I surmise that this is a neat way of ensuring that the food I provide for this little hedgehog is only likely to be eaten by the hedgehog - assuming they know what to do with it.

Comment: Actually cats will and do eat raw egg. Feral cats on a poultry farm where I worked ate any broken eggs in the egg grading room and I often gave my own cats raw egg, it gave their coat a beautiful sheen.

Answer (score 2):

Eggs are a good source of nutrients for hedgehogs, but it is not a common part of their diet so I don't think they will recognise it as food unless the shell is broken.

And a small hedgehog will probably have trouble opening an egg, larger hedgehogs might be able to open it if they see it as food.

Your idea is good if hedgehogs see it as food.

This is my opinion about it and i might be wrong, if it works please give some feedback; it can help others.

Answer (score 2):

They will be able to do it, however another way is to put a cracked egg out. Do not use milk, they are lactose intolerant and so ends up making them ill.

Comment: how do one avoid cats eating the egg before the hedgehog can eat it.

Comment: Cats won't typically go for eggs that have been exposed for too long, they are fussy

Answer (score 2):

I live on a farm and have chickens, and my friend came over for me to pet sit her hedgehog. We were at breakfast and I saw this question. I took a raw chicken egg, and the hedgehog ended up being a little bit afraid of the egg. He soon realized he could push it with his nose. I guess they don't destroy the eggs.

Answer (score 0):

We have put a storage box outside. A hole of 4 to 5 inch square, long enough for a cat not to reach in and pull the dish. Can stop this by placing a brick a few inches away from the entrance. Hedge will smell the food alright, they take to it quickly. Catfood in gravy not jelly, with no fish, and small cat biscuits, again not fish. Little one will thrive on it and if you can, make a shelter nearby somewhere quiet. Hope this helps